# Aframe Image transparency

Tags: html, image, overlay, transparency, aframe

I'm new to A-frame
I would like to add images with transparency (.png) into the scene. Apparently they cannot be overlay.
I use

```
    <a-image position="0 0 -20" material="transparent: true" width="32" height="19" src="#img1"></a-image>
```

And I got a square background color-like.

[The green image looks cut-cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auzHD.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The renderer won't find out properly which image is in front of another without the `material`'s `alpha-test:0.5` property set.

Here is an example [with](https://jsfiddle.net/j6qaagut/6/) and [without](https://jsfiddle.net/j6qaagut/4/) the `alpha-test`

Comment: Thanks ! However, that "alpha-test:0.5" property is kind of strange